# Firebase FCM token getting expired frequently

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

My Android App is built using capacitor Js, I converted my react Js web app into a native android app using capacitor Js.

I implemented firebase push notification capacitor plugin, what I do is, I generate device token using following code

```
PushNotifications.addListener('registration',
  (token: Token) => {
    alert('Push registration success, token: ' + token.value);
  }
);
```

On the client-side (android-device), I store the token in the database every time a user opens the app. Whenever I want to send a notification to a particular device I use the stored token to send a notification.

However, the token works only for a few days.
if the user doesn't open the app for more than a few days its associated token doesn't work and the user doesn't get any notifications and throws the following error

```
FirebaseMessagingError: Requested entity was not found.
```

is there anything that can help me out??

I would really appreciate it.